# Disabled people and formal bending body language (such as bowing or sitting)

Tags: colloquial-language

This question is not about written Japanese language, but about Japanese language spoken with the body (which, I think, is also relevant because when people use this bodily language in Japan they also simultaneously use some spoken language).

My question is, how does a disabled person, for example one with back or waist bending problems (if, any, in Japan, exists, otherwise we are only freaking with certain types of foreigners), deal with not being able to bend the waist or bend in other sitting positions?

Does the spoken language change with regards to not being able to assume certain postures as well, and, if so, in what ways, and in which particular contexts?

Could you please post some pictures as well, if possible?

Also, I think this is the most appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask this (so sorry if I could not find a better one).

Comment: It could be only me but I really don’t understand what this question is asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "Japanese language spoken with the body"? No matter what language you speak, a back problem alone will not prevent you from speaking.

Comment: Are you trying to ask about the different types of bowing that are done in Japan? I'm not sure that would count as "Japanese language" though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking about the bowing and the sitting on the floor, because, my impression is that if you cannot do those then you cannot communicate effectively in Japan. Am I right? In each case, what workarounds exist? Thanks.

Comment: It's like asking how a person with no arms deal with situations where you usually shake hands. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with any particular language.

Comment: But that is language as well. It fits in, because some one in that position ought to know what to do.

Comment: Bowing is a form of communication, but I don't think it's "Japanese language" (as defined by the parameters of this stack exchange) just because it's a form of communication used in Japan.

Comment: If it isn't language, what is it then?

Comment: I didn't say "it's not language." I said I don't think it's part of "the Japanese language." It's not part of 日本語.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it would simply result in less physical movement (e.g., all waist bowing replaced with a head lowering) and more explicit language to replace any impossible movement (申し訳ございません, お願いいたします, etc)

Any reasonable interlocutor would understand that there is a physical disability involved and not take any offense.